# Connect to server on Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, client-server, networkonmainthread

I'm trying to connect my device to a local server and send messages but I get this error when trying to connect: E/Error connect()(2016): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException .
My code is this:

```
//Connect
public boolean Connect() {
    //Get data from ip and port from editbox
    String IP = ipinput.getText().toString();
    int PORT = Integer.valueOf(portinput.getText().toString());

        //This is where the error is shown
    try {//create socket with IP + PORT values
        miCliente = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        //If it's connected
        if (miCliente.isConnected() == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Show error
        txtstatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        txtstatus.setText(" !!! ERROR  !!!");
        Log.e("Error connect()", "" + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried the AsyncTask but maybe I'm doing it wrong and I'm new to sockets. And yes my server is running. Thanks

Comment: If moving your code to AsyncTask.doInBackground didn't work, can you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add connect method in AsyncTask like below :

```
class MakeConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connect();
        return null;
    }

}
```

And execute AsyncTask like this :

```
new MakeConnectionTask().execute();
```

Comment: @Zack9807 If this helped, you might accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All network related operations must be done in a background thread, so if you're using an AsyncTask, make sure that all network calls (connect, read, write, etc) are in doInBackground.